# why is nullable validation not working in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**I have be able to findout what was the problem and the problem was in my migration table, i didn't make the website field   `nullable()`  so when i try to insert empty string into it, it becomes a problem.**

I have a field in my view form named "website", and I am making this field optional. That means any user can decide to input their website if they have one, or leave it empty.

```
 <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('website') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="website" class="col-md-4 control-label">Website</label>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input id="website" type="text" class="form-control" name="website" value="{{ old('website') }}" placeholder="ex. www.mytruck.com" autofocus>

                      @if ($errors->has('website'))
                          <span class="help-block">
                              <strong>{{ $errors->first('website') }}</strong>
                           </span>
                        @endif
               </div>
 </div>
```

and from the controller I have this validation code

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
         'website' => 'url|string|max:100|nullable',
     ]);
}


  protected function create(array $data)
   {
    return User::create([
           'website' => $data['website'],
```

Comment: try this; website' => 'sometimes|url|string|max:100|nullable

Comment: @lea_Kelmedi, thanks for your response, but i try it now i am getting this error message of The website format is invalid.

Comment: you can try 'url|max:100'

Comment: actually you are validating as url so nullable will not work

Comment: just tested this one and its working: 'url'=>'sometimes|nullable|url|string|max:100'

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi thank you for your assistance in but it still not working maybe my code is wrong somewhere

Comment: @FamousIghodaro yeah no problem, try to validate the data in constructor method and add my rules. They worked for me.

Comment: @FamousIghodaro What happens if you move "nullable" to be the first item?

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi There is a clear difference between nullable and sometimes, if you just put sometimes in there it means the field is not required to be present. If it is not present in this case this is not a valid response from the site I believe.

Comment: @milo526 if i try to put nullable to the first item, i get error of website can not be null

Comment: @milo526 sometimes rule means when it's present then it applies the following validation in his case nullable because it can be empty. If we don't apply nullable then sometimes will not pass it through validation therefore it will not pass the validation stage.

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi and milo526 thanks you guys for you assistance. I have be able to findout what was the problem and the problem was in my migration table

Comment: I removed (solved) from the title. If an answer solved it, consider accepting the answer or post one yourself. If not, you can delete the question.

Comment: Why you are adding nullable in validation instead of making this field in database as nullable clause by adding nullable from Migrations Then you just have to provide validations for url, max characters and string

Answer (score 0):

If you want a field to be optional, then you dont have to put "required" in the validation.

So in your case you can try: url|max:100

this only validate the field if you put any in it.

Comment: He never put required in any of his validation?

Comment: its just an explanation for what i think string and nullable are not needed in this validation.